No power to ceiling light
I have a ceiling light connected to one 3 way switch in a box in the hall  and to what appears to be one 4 way switch in a box in the kitchen. The circuit has been working normally until 2 days ago when it became impossible to turn on the light (3 bulbs in fixture-all replaced with known good ones).
No breakers in service box are tripped, all lights and outlets are working.
There is no voltage present on either switch.
I thought that a 4 way switch had a 3 way upstream and a 3 way downstream but I have lived in this house several years and know of no other 3 way or otherwise controlling this light.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Four way might have been handy at the time and is used as a three way, the same as a three way can be used as a single.  Back stabs are know for this problem if something happens, any should be changed to the screws.  With breaker off.  It should get power from closest receptacle if lucky.  Or might have Kentucky fried mice in the wall.  Might just be a loose wire nut also.  Power can go to switch first or to light first.  Make double sure there is no power or might have Kentucky fried fingers.
